# TKInter checkbox variable is always 0

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Python's TkInter module for a GUI. Below is a simple checkbox code.

```
def getCheckVal():
    print cbVar.get()

windowTime=Tk.Tk()
cbVar = Tk.IntVar()
btnC = Tk.Checkbutton(windowTime, text="Save", variable = cbVar, command=getCheckVal)
btnC.grid()
windowTime.mainloop()
```

This code works fine. Each time I tick the checkbox, I get 1, else 0.

However, when I run the same code in a function that is called from another TkInter command (when a button is pressed), it stops working. I always get 0 as the value.

```
class GUIMainClass:

    def __init__(self):
        '''Create the main window'''
        self.window = Tk.Tk()

    def askUser(self):
        def getCheckVal():
            print cbVar.get()

        windowTime=Tk.Tk()
        cbVar = Tk.IntVar()
        btnC = Tk.Checkbutton(windowTime, text="Save", variable = cbVar,
                              command=getCheckVal)
        btnC.grid()
        windowTime.mainloop()

    def cmdWindow(self):
        frameShow=Tk.Frame(self.window)
        frameShow.grid()
        btnSwitch = Tk.Button(frameShow, text='Show Plots', command=self.askUser)
        btnSwitch.grid()
        self.window.mainloop()

GUIObj=GUIMainClass()
GUIObj.cmdWindow()
```

This is very unusual. What could be going wrong?

EDIT: I've used 2 mainloops because I want a separate window (`windowTime`) to open up when I click "Show Plots" button. This new window should have the checkbox in it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `windowTime`, `cbVar`, etc. variables are defined in the function's local scope. When `askUser()` completes execution, those values are thrown away. Prepend `self.` to them to save them as instance variables.

There should only be one `mainloop()` in your program, to run the main `Tkinter` root object. Try putting it as the very last line in the program. I recommend doing some reading on [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) for how to set up a `Tkinter` application.

Comment: Also, I prepended `self` to everything. Didn't work.

Comment: There should still only be one `mainloop()` in a `tkinter` application. You don't need one per window. Please see my recommendation to read about the right way to set up a `tkinter` application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what all you're trying to do, but one problem is that the `TK.IntVar` called `cbVar` that you create in your `askUser()` method will be deleted when the function returns, so you need to attach it to something that will still exist after that happens. While you could make it a global variable, a better choice would be to make it an attribute of something more persistent and has a longer "lifespan".

Another likely issue is that generally there should only be one call to `mainloop()` in a single `Tkinter` application. It appears what you want to do is display what is commonly known as a *Dialog Window*, which Tkinter also supports. There's some standard ones built-in, plus some more generic classes to simplify creating custom ones. Here's some [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) I found which describes them in some detail. You may also find it helpful to look at their source code. 
In Python 2 it's in the [/Lib/lib-tk/tkSimpleDialog.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/lib-tk/tkSimpleDialog.py) file and 
in Python 3 the code's in a file named [/Lib/tkinter/simpledialog.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/tkinter/simpledialog.py).

Below is code that takes the latter approach and derives a custom dialog class named `GUIButtonDialog` from the generic one included the Tkinter library which is simply named `Dialog`.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as Tk    # Python 2
    from tkSimpleDialog import Dialog
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import tkinter as Tk    # Python 3
    from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog


class GUIButtonDialog(Dialog):
    """Custom one Button dialog box."""
    def __init__(self, btnText, parent=None, title=None):
        self.btnText = btnText
        Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title)

    def getCheckVal(self):
        print(self.cbVar.get())

    def body(self, master):
        """Create dialog body."""
        self.cbVar = Tk.IntVar()
        self.btnC = Tk.Checkbutton(master, text=self.btnText, variable=self.cbVar,
                                   command=self.getCheckVal)
        self.btnC.grid()

        return self.btnC  # Return the widget to get inital focus.

    def buttonbox(self):
        # Overridden to suppress default "OK" and "Cancel" buttons.
        pass


class GUIMainClass:

    def __init__(self):
        """Create the main window."""
        self.window = Tk.Tk()

    def askUser(self):
        """Display custom dialog window (until user closes it)."""
        GUIButtonDialog("Save", parent=self.window)

    def cmdWindow(self):
        frameShow = Tk.Frame(self.window)
        frameShow.grid()
        btnSwitch = Tk.Button(frameShow, text='Show Plots', command=self.askUser)
        btnSwitch.grid()
        self.window.mainloop()


GUIObj = GUIMainClass()
GUIObj.cmdWindow()
```

Comment: The checkbox should open in a new window. Here, it's in the same window.

Comment: sbhatla: OK, see my updated answer. Better late than never, no? `;¬)`