# Checkbox always reads 0 in popup window - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI using Tkinter, it has a main screen and then when you press a button a popup window appears, where you select a checkbutton and then a email will get sent to you. 
Not matter what I do, I cannot read the value of the checkbutton as `1` or `True` it always = `0` or `False`.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Status')
CheckVar1 = IntVar()
def email():
    class PopUp(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)

            popup = tk.Toplevel(self, background='gray20')
            popup.wm_title("EMAIL")
            self.withdraw()
            popup.tkraise(self)
            topframe = Frame(popup, background='gray20')
            topframe.grid(column=0, row=0)

            bottomframe = Frame(popup, background='gray20')
            bottomframe.grid(column=0, row=1)

            self.c1 = tk.Checkbutton(topframe, text="Current", variable=CheckVar1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=2, width=15, background='gray20', foreground='snow', selectcolor='gray35', activebackground='gray23', activeforeground='snow')
            self.c1.pack(side="left", fill="x", anchor=NW)           
            label = tk.Label(bottomframe, text="Please Enter Email Address", background='gray20', foreground='snow')
            label.pack(side="left", anchor=SW, fill="x", pady=10, padx=10)
            self.entry = tk.Entry(bottomframe, bd=5, width=35, background='gray35', foreground='snow')
            self.entry.pack(side="left", anchor=S, fill="x", pady=10, padx=10)
            self.button = tk.Button(bottomframe, text="OK", command=self.on_button, background='gray20', foreground='snow')
            self.button.pack(side="left", anchor=SE, padx=10, pady=10, fill="x")

        def on_button(self):
            address = self.entry.get() 
            print(address)
            state = CheckVar1.get()
            print (state)
            time.sleep(2)
            self.destroy()


    app = PopUp()
    app.update()

tk.Button(root, 
            text="EMAIL", 
            command=email, 
            background='gray15', 
            foreground='snow').pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill="both", anchor=N)

screen = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=475, background='gray15')
screen.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, fill="both", expand=True)


def latest():
    #Other code
    root.after(300000, latest)
root.mainloop()
```

The popup works perfectly, and the email will print when entered but the value of checkbox is always 0.

I have tried:

`CheckVar1 = tk.IntVar()` - No success

`self.CheckVar1` & `self.CheckVar1.get()` - No success

Removing `self.withdraw()` - No success

I only have one `root.mainloop()` in the script, I am using `app.update()` for the popup window because without this it will not open.

I have checked these existing questions for solution and none have helped:
Self.withdraw  - [Can't make tkinter checkbutton work normally when running as script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627304/cant-make-tkinter-checkbutton-work-normally-when-running-as-script)
Self.CheckVar1 - [TKInter checkbox variable is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616632/tkinter-checkbox-variable-is-always-0)
Only one instance of mainloop() - [Python tkinter checkbutton value always equal to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432539/python-tkinter-checkbutton-value-always-equal-to-0)

I have also checked very similar questions but I wasn't going to post them all.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using `BooleanVar()` instead of `IntVar()`? See a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43970664/3991125

Comment: @albert Yes I have tried `BooleanVar()` and I always get `False`

Comment: **BIG NO GO**, you are using `tk.Tk` more than **once**. This leads to unexspected behavior. Change `class PopUp(tk.Tk):` to `class PopUp(tk.Toplevel):`

Comment: @stovfl Thank you, this is what the issue was. Working perfectly now. Also moved `CheckVar1` into the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of variable scope

try to put **CheckVar1 = IntVar()** inside the class

use it with self like this

```
self.CheckVar1 = tk.IntVar() # object of int

self.CheckVar1.set(1) # set value

variable=self.CheckVar1 # passing to the checkbutton as parameter 

state = self.CheckVar1.get() # getting value
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have two root windows. Each root window gets its own internal tcl interpreter, and the widgets and tkinter variables in one are completely invisible to the other. You're creating the `IntVar` in the first root window, and then trying to associate it with a checkbutton in a second root window. This cannot work. You should always only have a single instance of `Tk` in a tkinter program.